# Compiling TensorFlow 1.4.0 GPU on Windows 10 x64

Tags: windows, tensorflow

There doesn't seem to be any detailed documentation for how to compile TensorFlow 1.4.0 GPU on Windows 10 x64.

I need to recompile TF to add missing functionality for a Windows 7 x64 production system.

The official Google link at [Installing TensorFlow from Sources](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) just says

> We don't officially support building TensorFlow on Windows; however,
>   you may try to build TensorFlow on Windows if you don't mind using the
>   highly experimental Bazel on Windows or TensorFlow CMake build.

Okay fine, I can use Bazel to try to compile something like

```
bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --config=cuda -k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

but how do I incorporate the Python and NVIDIA dependencies into that build?

Should I use CMake instead?

How were the Windows wheels at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow-gpu compiled?

Comment: Use `cmake`, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the [answer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13962) from Adriano Carmezim over at github. The complete instructions for building TensorFlow on Windows, including making Windows Python wheels are at: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md

Additional issues are addressed on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5600)

Answer (score 0):

To build tensorflow on windows use cMake.